# Role no updated in time while trying to retrieve userInfo after user logged in auth0

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0

I’m using auth0 for my angular application. In the ngOnInit() of my app.component.ts I use this code:

```
this.authService.user$.subscribe(async (profile) => {
     await this.userService.getUserInfo(profile?.name!).then((result: ResponseJson) => {
         //here I set the role on the localStorage
     })
});
```

Where authService is imported from ‘@auth0/auth0-angular’;

The purpose of this is to call an userInfo api to get all the informations about user (including role) after that the user is logged in, so that I can have the mail to get those userInfo.
The problem is that, because the authService.user$ is sync, the flow doesn’t wait for the userInfo api and for the next setting of the role in localStorage, the flow continue, and so the role isn’t changed for the app at first time and I have to reload again the page.

There isn’t an async version that I can use for wait that the process will be finished? Or there isn’t another approach that I can use to get the same result?

If you need some other informations, let me know.

Thanks in advance!